# Send Parameter to Multiple Subroutines in Perl Module

Tags: perl, oop, parameters, perl-module, subroutine

I'm creating a user module to extract user information and currently I have:

```
sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my ( $id ) = @_;
    my $self = getUserInfo ($id);
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub getUserInfo
{
    ...
}
```

However, I would like to achieve something to the effect of:

```
my $self = (getFirstName($id), getLastName($id), getEmpNum($id));

...

sub getFirstName{ return { firstname => $firstname }; }
sub getLastName{ return { lastname => $lastname }; }
sub getEmpNum{ return { empnum => $empnum }; }
```

How do I go about distributing a parameter to multiple subroutines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your general code architecture has a few problems, but the snippets so far don't offer enough context to suggest an alternative solution – consider posting your complete code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for a more complete criticism.

Regarding your immediate problem: You could write a function to combine the hash references:

```
use Carp ();

sub combine_hashrefs {
    my %combined;
    for my $hashref (@_) {
        if (my @conflicts = grep { exists $combined{$_} } keys %$hashref) {
            Carp::confess "The keys [@conflicts] are conflicting";
        }
        @combined{keys %$hashref} = values %$hashref;
    }
    return \%combined;
}

...

my $self = combine_hashrefs($hashref_a, $hashref_b, $hashref_c, ...);
```

Comment: You are correct.. I reworked and finished with one subroutine doing all of the work here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGbLd

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand correctly that you want to avoid the repetition of `$id` in the following line?

```
my $self = (getFirstName($id), getLastName($id), getEmpNum($id));
```

`$self` is a scalar, so you should rather use the anonymous array `[...]`. To specify `$id` only once, you can use

```
my $self = [ map $_->($id), \&getFirstName, \&getLastName, \&getEmpNum ];
```